# Mmap, void pointer and type casting in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, mmap, void-pointers

I'm reading C on disk hash table code without knowing much about C or `mmap` but i know Golang.

This piece of code confuses me.
There are two structs like this.

```
typedef struct HashTbl
{
    void *data;
    ...
} HashTbl;
typedef struct Header
{
    char magic[16];
    size_t total;
    size_t used;
} Header;
```

It uses `mmap` to map `HashTbl` `data` property

```
ht->data = mmap(NULL, data_size, prot, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
```

`ht` type is `HashTbl`, `ht->data` would be cast to `Header` to set property value like this:

```
Header *h = (Header *)ht->data;
strcpy(h->magic, MAGIC_STR);
h->total = 12;
h->used = 0;
```

Then this function:

```
void *hashtable_of(HashTbl *ht)
{
    return (unsigned char *)ht->data + sizeof(Header);
}
```

usage of this function:

```
uint64_t *table = (uint64_t *)hashtable_of(ht);
```

I don't understand what's the purpose of this function, is that to calculate the length of `void pointer (Header::data)` value?

`void pointer` in C seems like `interface{}` in Go, which could be cast to any type.
but Go has error handling while doing type casting, if we cast `interface{}` type to wrong type, it would return the error

But in this C code, it casts a `Struct` -> `unsigned char pointer` and combine it to `sizeof` other struct, which means `unsigned char pointer` is an integer?!

How is that even possible?

Comment: I do not no nothing about Go but in C any pointer is an unsigned integer (as it's a memory address). The pointer type represent the type of the variable that is pointed, and not the pointer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it casts a `Struct` -> `unsigned char pointer` and combine it to sizeof other struct, which means unsigned char pointer is an integer?

```
void *hashtable_of(HashTbl *ht)
{
    return (unsigned char *)ht->data + sizeof(Header);
}
```

Not quite.  Code is starting with one pointer, `ht` and determining another pointer, the return pointer.

There is not cast of a `struct`.  There is a cast of a `unsigned char *`.

There are no integers in this code aside from `sizeof(Header)`.

---

Let us take it in steps:

The *pointer* `ht` has member `.data` which is de-referenced by `ht->data`.  That results in a `void *`.

The `void *` is cast to an `unsigned char` pointer.

Next, code performs pointer addition with `... +  sizeof(Header)`.  Pointer addition is *like* integer addition, yet has differences.  Here the addition of a pointer and integer results in another `unsigned char` pointer that is `sizeof(Header)` bytes (`unsigned char`) further along in memory.

Lastly this `unsigned char` pointer is converted to a `void *` as part of the `return`.

---

`hashtable_of()` overall usage is unclear without the surrounding code.

---

> `void pointer` in C seems like interface{} in Go, which could be cast to any type.

Almost.  A `void` pointer can be cast to any *object* pointer with restrictions of value validity and alignment.  A `void` pointer may be insufficient to represent a *function* pointer though. C lacks a 100% portable universal pointer.

Comment: i updated the code with usage of above func `uint64_t *table = (uint64_t *)hashtable_of(ht);` it casts `void *` into `uint64_t`, i still don't understand how `data` can be cast to `unsigned char pointer` , and what's the goal of that func

Comment: @TomSawyer Detail: That is not a cast  from `void *` to `uint64_t` (an integer). It is a cast of a `void *`  to `uint64_t *`, a pointer to another kind of pointer.  The goal of the function is to retrieve the address of data (rather than the data itself) stored in a hashtable and present it as a `void*` for subsequent assignment to various pointer types.

Comment: @TomSawyer Difficult to fully say for certain as only snippets of code are here, but `data`  in `struct HashTbl` is more likely a pointer to the _data_, rather than the data itself.  C passes pointers to data around a lot, rather than the _data_.